# Input value in a Field should raise a message Popover Error

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a requriment to modify an existing SAP UI5 Application. The problem is this application isn´t written by me, So sometimes it's very hard for me to understand the application. But now i have a problem as below:

I have 2 fields: NetTons and GrossTons. Where **GrossTons = NetTons * 1,5**.

I want to show a Message Popover if the GrossTons <= 500 kg. I found the piece of code in the app where I can get the Value of the GrossTons but I don´t know how to implement the Message Popover control.

```
netTonsPerTrainChange: function (oEvent, addParam) {
        var table = this.byId("volumeEditTable");
        var col = addParam.col;
        var oCtrl = oEvent.getSource();
        var val = parseFloat(oCtrl.getValue(), 10);
        var oGrossTons = this.getCellAt(table, {row: GROSSTONS, col: col});
        oGrossTons.setValue(val * GTONFACTOR);
        //Check auf Bruttotonnen ob unter 500 kg
        var oCheckGrossTons = oGrossTons.getValue();

        if (oCheckGrossTons <= 500) {
            // 

        }
```

Comment: refer this link https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.MessagePopover/sample/sap.m.sample.MessagePopoverMessageHandling/code/controller%2FMessagePopoverMessageHandling.controller.js

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I know that there is the SAP UI5 DEMOKIT site, but in some examples i find it very hard to understand what they are doing -.-

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const oInput = this.getView().byId('inputID');
    oInput.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error); // or just "Error"
    oInput.setValueStateText("More than 500kg is not Ok"); // use i18n
```

Consider to manage this values in a JSON-Model & don`t forget to use i18n instead of the hardcoded text in productive system.

[see also](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/message-popover/)